# Internal Server Error when Redirecting page to another page

Tags: c#

I am trying to redirect the user after he/she logged in to his/her account using this code below.

```
if (Session["LoggedUser"] != null) HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("appHunt_IndexPage.html"); else HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("login.html");
```

but It cannot redirect the page. What is wrong with this code?? can someone help me with this.. thank you.

Edits

Here is the image of error.
[image]

I did not see the exception. Please help!

Comment: Internal Server Error means that there is some exception thrown. Have you try to debug?  Do you find it?

Comment: @vasily.sib , sir I attached the image of the console where the error is shown. Thank you sir.

Comment: @vasily.sib , YES SIR, I debug it and there is no error when executing the sql statements and also it retrieves the data from the table. but when the debugger hit that line of code. it will shown the error on the console.

Comment: Images of exceptions are [useless](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/). Can you just copy-paste it?

Comment: You need to debug the backend code. The front end exception is a symptom of the backend exception. Attach the debugger to your website and share the exception you're getting from the backend.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, Yes sir.. the only problem is the `Response.Redirect` . Actually, I am new to web development thats why I am asking for help in here

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. Please also include a screenshot of the `Network` tab (scrolled to the bottom, with `Preserve log` checked).

Comment: @AlexAbulencia do you understand how to debug a C# application? Not front end in the browser ... back end where the C# executes. Perhaps you should start there.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead. Yes Sir. I just said that I did debug the c# code. But then, the error exist in `Response.Redirect` .

Comment: Actually issue is with your web service not with page redirect.So the ode you pasted won't help

Comment: Check if your web service is working correctly or any issue there

Comment: @Shubham what do you mean my webservice sir?

Answer (score 0):

While Redirecting to another page(only specify page name in redirect function), Page should be on the same folder from where it redirects.

In your case, appHunt_IndexPage.html and login.html pages should be on the same folder else you need to specify a full path.

If your pages on root folder then use following code else specify your path after `~/`

Note:`~/` means to start from the root.

```
if (Session["LoggedUser"] != null) 
   HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/appHunt_IndexPage.html");
else 
   HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/login.html");
```